# Can only edit one object in a database in Django - why?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have created a booking system whereby users can have multiple bookings. I am trying to create a way for users to edit these bookings and have created the following mechanism.

Users book -> object created in database -> users can see upcoming bookings listed on upcoming template -> users can change the booking.

Where I am running into the issue is when I am trying to access the editing view. Essentially when the edit button is clicked, regardless of the booking it will always take the user to the booking form of the first object in the database but not the related one.

See code below:

models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    unique_id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    coursename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    daterequired = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    students = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    length = models.IntegerField()
    matches = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='matches')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Booking, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

views.py

```
def upcoming(request):
    booking = Booking.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    for bookings in booking:
        return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/upcoming.html', {'booking':booking})
    return redirect('teachers:book')

def addstudents(request, unique_id):
    booking = Booking.objects.get(unique_id=unique_id)
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        form = BookingForm(data=request.POST, instance=booking)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
        return redirect('teachers:upcoming')
    else:
        booking_dict = model_to_dict(booking)
        form = BookingForm(booking_dict)
        return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/adding.html', {'form':form})
```

urls.py

```
 path('teachers/', include(([
        path('', teachers.QuizListView.as_view(), name='quiz_change_list'),
        path('choose/', teachers.choose, name='choose'),
        path('book/', teachers.book, name='book'),
        path('addstudents/<uuid:unique_id>', teachers.addstudents, name='studentadd'),
        path('upcoming/', teachers.upcoming, name='upcoming'),
    ], 'classroom'), namespace='teachers')),
```

upcoming.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Upcoming Bookings
      <a href="{% url 'teachers:book' %}" style="float:right !important;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Book More</a>
    </div>
    {% for bookings in booking %}
    <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);" class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ bookings.coursename }}</h5>
      <p class="card-title"><strong>Unique Course ID:</strong> {{ bookings.unique_id }}</p>
      <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ bookings.daterequired }}</span>
      <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ bookings.students }} Students.</span>
      <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ bookings.length }} Hours.</span>
      <button style="float: right !important;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Student List</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Student List</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for matches in bookings.matches.all %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ matches }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <a href="{% url 'teachers:studentadd' bookings.unique_id%}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add More Students</button></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        exclude = ['user', ]
        widgets = {
            'students': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Number of Students'}),
            'length': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'Time needed in hours'}),
            'coursename': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'Name of your course for students'}),
        }
        labels = {
            'daterequired': 'What date and time do you require?',
            'coursename': 'Name of Upcoming Course'
        }
```

Linking structure:
[image: Linking structure]

AddStudents form:
[image: firn]

FYI - add students is the booking form editing page.

Can anyone tell me why no matter what I can only edit the first object in the database?

Comment: So where is the form that is submitting to addstudents?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated above

Comment: But how is that form being output for a specific booking? I can't understand the flow and where you are having trouble. And also why for example do you have a return inside your for loop in `upcoming`? What's the point of all those variables there which you don't use?

Comment: See above changed. I have attached an image to show you the edit form I am discussing along with the url structure. I have a for loop because if no bookings exist I want to redirect to another view. I have removed the variables thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. What does this "Add booking" screenshot have to do with adding students to an existing course? I think you need to cut your problem back to the basics, and show the relevant code.

Comment: The add booking is simply labelled wrong - the only field with relevance is the many to many matches field where the user needs to be able to edit the students.

Comment: Well, you should really name things what they are, but never mind. But still your question is unclear. This is one form, so my original question stands: where is the code that is supposed to be responsible for displaying a *specific* form?

Comment: (Note, this issue of not calling things what they are seems to be a wider problem in your code - why is the set of students called "matches", why do you name the collection of bookings "booking" and the singular "bookings", and so on.)